# migrating wordpress website from localhost in windows to centos7

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost, wamp, centos7

I 've created a wordpress website in localhost in windows os using WAMP. now I want to migrate the website to **CentOS 7**. I have oracle VM and i installed **CentOS 7** on it.

How can I transfer the database and the files to CentOS 7 ?

Comment: Try this https://www.wpexplorer.com/migrating-wordpress-website/

Comment: improved formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the All In One WP Migration plugin.

Install it on you local site, click on export link in the plugin.
Before exporting add search / replace rule. Usually this is done if you have different domain.

If your local domain is http://domain.local you need to replace it with the new domain http://newdomain.com and click export to file.

[Screenshot of how to do that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PnIQ.png)

Then install the same plugin on the new host and use the import functionality to import the exported file.

This will migrate your whole site with database, content, images. Everything.

If you have problem with importing size of the file, you can increase the size on the new host by adding the following to the .htaccess file

`php_value upload_max_filesize 256M
php_value post_max_size 256M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300`

or you can [check this tutorial](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-increase-the-maximum-file-upload-size-in-wordpress/)

Comment: thank you so much Martin for your answer. I will try it

Comment: I tried every things worked fine. But I cannot increase the maximum upload file size more than 8M in centos 7. Do you know why? Is this related to the VM settings ??